# How to use inline fragment in useStaticQuery with Gatsby.js?

Tags: javascript, github, graphql, gatsby

I want to get a count of commits for each repository in my github using the useStaticQuery hook from gatsbyJs and Graphql. Getting this error: `Unknown type "Commit".` for this query:

```
const {
    github: {
      viewer: {
        repositories: { edges },
      },
    },
  } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      {
        github {
          viewer {
            repositories(first: 6, orderBy: { field: STARGAZERS, direction: DESC }) {
              edges {
                node {
                  stargazers {
                    totalCount
                  }
                  object(expression: "master") {
                    ... on Commit {
                      history(first: 1) {
                        edges {
                          node {
                            committedDate
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  );
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? Is `Commit` an available fragment? How do you know that? Check: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/graphql-data-layer/using-graphql-fragments/

Comment: Yes I know it is available I got it to work on the github graphql explorer, however that doesn't use useStaticQuery. https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer. Not sure if the syntax differs at all for the useStaticQueryHook.